# Mapping for array of geo_point fields in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I'd like to persist some JSON to elastic(search) that looks a little like this:

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "points": [
    { "lat": 0.0, "lon": 0.0 },
    { "lat": 1.0, "lon": 1.0 }
  ]
}
```

Points being a list of the type geo_point in elastic. Because they're geo_point values I need to define the index mapping, but the closest I can see is to do this:

```
"place": {
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "points": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which would mean having each point be a map with a single key of location and a geo_point value. I just want the geo_points, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your mapping as below :

```
"place": {
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "points": {  // <--  it can also be a multi-valued field if you insert multiple values, as skal88 mentioned, your json would perfectly fit in this mapping.
      "type": "geo_point" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have in mind that the new ElasticSearch 6.7 (throws a warning) and 7.0 will have to place mappings as follows: PUT geopoint_test/_mappings?include_type_name=false
{
 "properties": {
   "location": {
    "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }

Answer (score 4):

Yes. When you define a mapping, the values inside field can be single or array of the specific "type". You need only insert on this value a array of geo_points. Some like this:

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "points": [
    { lat: 41.12, lon: 2.023 },
    { lat: 30, lon: 4.1 }
  ]
}
```