# ElasticSearch : Assigning an array of GPS locations to an entity

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

Is it possible to assign an array of GPS locations to an entity ?

Say for an example,  my entity is a Wine. And I want to link the GPS locations of the bars a particular Wine is sold.

Then during search ,I want to retrieve the Wine products sold in a given perimeter

(of course I have other search functionalities to search Wines by name, year,type..etc. I have already implemented these.Now I want to add this GPS based search).

[Update]
Apologize, I found the answer at :
[Mapping for array of geo_point fields in elastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047741/mapping-for-array-of-geo-point-fields-in-elastic)

Comment: Yes, nothing prevents you from adding multiple location fields to a given document

Comment: i meant as an array

Comment: Yes, an array is fine too.